# Как реализовать сброс выполнения POST запроса при поступлении очередного POST запроса

Tags: python, django, post

В общем задача следующая: на сервер приходит POST запрос, и поистечении 30 секунд мне нужно выполнять какое-то действие, но если 30 сек. еще не прошли, но пришел еще один POST запрос, то нужно обнулять таймер(30сек.) и делать все с начала (ждать 30 сек. и если пришел POST запрос то обнулять)

Подскажите пожалуйста как такое реализовать в python django 2.2(последней версии)
Заранее благодарю!)

Answer (score 0):

Как не самый оптимальный вариант, предлагаю при получении POST запроса сразу писать в определенную модель в определенное поле дату последнего POST запроса и через определнное кол-во дейсввий чекать ее изменение. Если изменилась и нужно прервать - прерываете, а новый POST запрос будет работать как надо

```
class PostModel(models.Model):
    last_time = models.DateTimeField(...)


def post_30_sec(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if PostModel.objects.exists():
            pm = PostModel.objects.first()
            pm.last_time = localtime()
            pm.save()
        else:
            pm = PostModel.objects.create(last_time=localtime())

        # do to-do to-do-do-do
        pm.refresh_from_db()
        if localtime() - localtime(pm.last_time) > timedelta(second=30): raise Exception # or another action


        # do to-do to-do-do-do

        pm.refresh_from_db()
        if localtime() - localtime(pm.last_time) > timedelta(second=30): raise Exception # or another action

        # if we do all before 40 secons exit successfully
        return HttpResponse(...)
    raise Http404
```

Comment: Za Ars, А что если действие нужно ровно через 30 сек. сделать? Можно ли в модели включить таймер?